# poor prediction in x**2 regression in pytorch

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to replicate the code available in https://machinelearningmastery.com/neural-networks-are-function-approximators/ using pytorch and adding train and test data but the prediction and loss results are not good.

In first attempt, I tried to change deep network nodes, epochs and learning rate, then
I tried to add scheduler to adjust learning rate and I implemented a small checkpoint to save the good models but still it was not enough to get good results.

I was wondering if the community have any idea to fix my code.

DATA

```
X = torch.arange(start, end, step, dtype=torch.float32).unsqueeze(dim=1)
y = torch.tensor([i**2.0 for i in X[0:]]).unsqueeze(dim=1)

train_split = int (0.8 *len(X))
X_train, y_train = X[:train_split], y[:train_split]
X_test , y_test = X[train_split:], y[train_split:]

scaler_x = MinMaxScaler()
scaler_x.fit(X_train)
X_Train = scaler_x.transform(X_train)


scaler_y = MinMaxScaler()
scaler_y.fit(y_train)
y_Train = scaler_y.transform(y_train)
```

Deep Network

```
class FunctionEstimatorModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.linear_layer_1 = nn.Linear(in_features = 1,out_features = 200)
        self.relu = nn.LeakyReLU()
        self.linear_layer_2 = nn.Linear(in_features = 200,out_features = 200)
        self.relu = nn.LeakyReLU()
        self.linear_layer_3 = nn.Linear(in_features = 200,out_features = 1)



    def forward (self, x: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
        return self.linear_layer_3(self.relu(self.linear_layer_2(self.relu(self.linear_layer_1(x)))))
```

for loop

```
for epoch in range(epochs):

    model_0.train()
    y_preds = model_0(X_train).squeeze()
    loss = loss_fn(y_preds, y_train)
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    scheduler.step()


#####Testing 
    model_0.eval()

    with torch.inference_mode():
        test_pred = model_0(X_test).squeeze()
        test_loss = loss_fn(test_pred, y_test)

    print(f"Epoch: {epoch} | Loss: {loss} | Test Loss: {test_loss}")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSnst.png)

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I should point out that compared to the tutorial page you referencing, the points you are trying to predict are much more difficult because they are out of distribution. That's because your model is only able to predict points within the `[-50, 25]` since it was only ever given training points belonging to that interval. If you look at the example from the page, however, his training points cover the whole range (with a different density of course but still).